# Частотный криптоанализ зашифрованного текста

Tags: шифрование, информатика

Дан текст (изначально все слова по 5 букв, но преподаватель сказал, что это не имеет значения, это просто условность, можно убрать пробелы) без знаков препинания, в нем зашифровано стихотворение:

ДМВМР ОЕРЁХ ТВУУЩ КФЭДВ ЛДМВМ РЛЙЖО НЖХЕВ ЁЭДВЛ ПВУФР НГРДР ЛЁРТР ИЖПЮМ ЖУРЪН КУЮУЖ ОЮОХИ КМРДУ ЖОЮДТ ЖОЖПП РРГБЙ ВППЭЧ СРЁФБ ПХФРЛ ЕХГЖТ ПККХЖ ЙЁВФЖ ТСКЕР ТЖДВС ХУФРС РТРИП ЖЛДРН РУФКК ЙУОЖИ ПЭЧЁЖ ТЖДЖП ЮЙВСН ВФРДВ ЁЭТБЖ ДВТВЙ ХФРДВ ЙПРГК ЪКПВЕ РТЖНР ДВПЖЖ НРДВП ЖХТРИ ВЛМВФ РИУРЪ НКУБК ЙВУСР ТКНКМ РОХИК ДЖФУБ ДЖУЖН РДРНЮ ЕРФПР ПВТХУ КТРОВ ПУМВЙ ВНСРО ЖЫКМХ ЁЖОЮБ ПУМВЙ ВНЩКП РДПКМ ХНХМВ УМВЙВ НСРСХ МХСЩК ПЖФРН УФРСХ ЙРОХУ МВЙВН КГТВФ ЮБЕХГ КПЭКД ВПКОК ФТРЁР ТУФВТ КМСВЧ РОСРФ ХИКНУ БКОРН ДКНДЙ ЖОНАЕ НБЁАЩ КДЖНЮ ОРИПР ОХГРБ ТКПХО КПКУФ ТХЕРУ ХЁВТЖ ДХВСТ РДУМВ ЙВНШВ ТАОХИ КМЩФР ГЭМДФ ЖОБЪК ФУБДГ ВЪМХМ ВМВБГ НВИЮМ РНРОЖ ЖРФФХ ЁРДВП ЖДЭГЮ ЖЪЮХС КТВАФ УБДУБ МПВУД РЖОУФ РКФФВ МРЛНК УСРТЙ ВФЖБН КЩФРЁ ХОВАФ СТРЧР ИКЖЙП ВФЮМН ВЁПВЪ НКТЖГ БФХЪМ ККЁЖН БФОЖИ УРГРЛ

Символ р встречается 66 раз. Частота 8.67%
Символ в встречается 55 раз. Частота 7.23%
Символ к встречается 43 раз. Частота 5.65%
Символ ж встречается 42 раз. Частота 5.52%
Символ ф встречается 34 раз. Частота 4.47%
Символ у встречается 33 раз. Частота 4.34%
Символ п встречается 31 раз. Частота 4.07%
Символ н встречается 31 раз. Частота 4.07%
Символ д встречается 31 раз. Частота 4.07%
Символ х встречается 31 раз. Частота 4.07%
Символ т встречается 28 раз. Частота 3.68%
Символ м встречается 28 раз. Частота 3.68%
Символ о встречается 25 раз. Частота 3.29%
Символ б встречается 18 раз. Частота 2.37%
Символ й встречается 17 раз. Частота 2.23%
Символ с встречается 17 раз. Частота 2.23%
Символ ё встречается 15 раз. Частота 1.97%
Символ и встречается 13 раз. Частота 1.71%
Символ ю встречается 13 раз. Частота 1.71%
Символ г встречается 13 раз. Частота 1.71%
Символ л встречается 9 раз. Частота 1.18%
Символ е встречается 9 раз. Частота 1.18%
Символ э встречается 8 раз. Частота 1.05%
Символ ъ встречается 8 раз. Частота 1.05%
Символ щ встречается 6 раз. Частота 0.79%
Символ а встречается 5 раз. Частота 0.66%
Символ ч встречается 4 раз. Частота 0.53%
Символ ы встречается 1 раз. Частота 0.13%
Символ ш встречается 1 раз. Частота 0.13%

Сравнил с наиболее встречающимися буквами в алфавите и провел замену, но получается полная чушь, может кто подсказать хотя бы корректный способ это расшифровать?

Comment: Ну, почитайте книжки по криптоанализу. Кто вам сказал, что ряд вероятностей появления букв всегда точно совпадает с рядом частот шифртекста?

Comment: Если работаете вручную — пробуйте заменять самые частые буквы шифртекста на самые частые буквы языка и пытаться угадывать, похожи ли на что-нибудь слова. Если не получается, возьмите таблицу сочетаемости букв и прогоните текст по ней, а затем совместите результаты двух анализов.

Comment: И кстати, пробел вы зачем учитываете в частотном анализе? Сами же сказали, что он не нужен. Ясный пень, ерунда получается.

Comment: Изначальный текст разделен пробелом по 5 букв, со слов преподавателя, пробелы не имеют ценности, так просто проще, сейчас отредактируют и уберу строку с частотой появления пробелов. Книжку просто физически не успею прочитать, дан ограниченный дедлайн до 10 ноября

Comment: За пять дней можно при желании изучить здоровенный том. Но если у вас настолько не хватает времени, могу посоветовать прочитать раздел про шифр замены книги Жданова "Криптоанализ классических шифров". Там всего страниц двадцать, можно прочесть за четверть часа. Сам когда-то по этой книге учил основы криптоанализа.

Comment: И зачем читать всю книжку, не пойму? У вас вся книга по шифру замены? Да там при желании больше, чем на тридцать страниц не размажешь.

Answer (score 2):

Через частотный анализ не удалось найти ключ, про шифр Цезаря в вопросе нет упоминаний.

Ключ:

```
  {'А': 'ю', 'Б': 'я', 'В': 'а', 'Г': 'б', 'Д': 'в', 'Е': 'г', 'Ё': 'д', 'Ж': 
'е', 'З': 'ё', 'И': 'ж', 'Й': 'з', 'К': 'и', 'Л': 'й', 'М': 'к', 'Н': 'л', 'О':
 'м', 'П': 'н', 'Р': 'о', 'С': 'п', 'Т': 'р', 'У': 'с', 'Ф': 'т', 'Х': 'у', 'Ц':
 'ф', 'Ч': 'х', 'Ш': 'ц', 'Щ': 'ч', 'Ъ': 'ш', 'Ы': 'щ', 'Ь': 'ъ', 'Э': 'ы', 'Ю':
 'ь', 'Я': 'э'}
```

Brute force:

```
t = '''ДМВМР ОЕРЁХ ТВУУЩ КФЭДВ ЛДМВМ РЛЙЖО НЖХЕВ ЁЭДВЛ ПВУФР НГРДР ЛЁРТР ИЖПЮМ ЖУРЪН КУЮУЖ ОЮОХИ КМРДУ ЖОЮДТ ЖОЖПП РРГБЙ ВППЭЧ СРЁФБ ПХФРЛ ЕХГЖТ ПККХЖ ЙЁВФЖ ТСКЕР ТЖДВС ХУФРС РТРИП ЖЛДРН РУФКК ЙУОЖИ ПЭЧЁЖ ТЖДЖП ЮЙВСН ВФРДВ ЁЭТБЖ ДВТВЙ ХФРДВ ЙПРГК ЪКПВЕ РТЖНР ДВПЖЖ НРДВП ЖХТРИ ВЛМВФ РИУРЪ НКУБК ЙВУСР ТКНКМ РОХИК ДЖФУБ ДЖУЖН РДРНЮ ЕРФПР ПВТХУ КТРОВ ПУМВЙ ВНСРО ЖЫКМХ ЁЖОЮБ ПУМВЙ ВНЩКП РДПКМ ХНХМВ УМВЙВ НСРСХ МХСЩК ПЖФРН УФРСХ ЙРОХУ МВЙВН КГТВФ ЮБЕХГ КПЭКД ВПКОК ФТРЁР ТУФВТ КМСВЧ РОСРФ ХИКНУ БКОРН ДКНДЙ ЖОНАЕ НБЁАЩ КДЖНЮ ОРИПР ОХГРБ ТКПХО КПКУФ ТХЕРУ ХЁВТЖ ДХВСТ РДУМВ ЙВНШВ ТАОХИ КМЩФР ГЭМДФ ЖОБЪК ФУБДГ ВЪМХМ ВМВБГ НВИЮМ РНРОЖ ЖРФФХ ЁРДВП ЖДЭГЮ ЖЪЮХС КТВАФ УБДУБ МПВУД РЖОУФ РКФФВ МРЛНК УСРТЙ ВФЖБН КЩФРЁ ХОВАФ СТРЧР ИКЖЙП ВФЮМН ВЁПВЪ НКТЖГ БФХЪМ ККЁЖН БФОЖИ УРГРЛ'''
t = ''.join(t.split()).strip()

sz='абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
sk='АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ'
z=list(sz)
dk={}
for i in range(len(z)):
    for j,l in zip(sk,z):
        dk[j]=l
    tr=[]
    for n in t:
        tr.append(dk[n])
    print(''.join(tr))
    z.append(z.pop(0))
    print(dk)
```

Результат:

```
В каком году - рассчитывай,
В какой земле - угадывай,
На столбовой дороженьке
Сошлись семь мужиков:
Семь временнообязанных,
Подтянутой губернии,
Уезда Терпигорева,
Пустопорожней волости,
Из смежных деревень:
Заплатова, Дыряева,
Разутова, Знобишина,
Горелова, Неелова -
Неурожайка тож,
Сошлися - и заспорили:
Кому живется весело,
Вольготно на Руси?

Роман сказал: помещику,
Демьян сказал: чиновнику,
Лука сказал: попу.
Купчине толстопузому!-
Сказали братья Губины,
Иван и Митродор.
Старик Пахом потужился
И молвил, в землю глядючи:
Вельможному боярину,
Министру государеву.
А Пров сказал: царю...

Мужик что бык: втемяшится
В башку какая блажь -
Колом ее оттудова
Не выбьешь: упираются,
Всяк на своем стоит!
Такой ли спор затеяли,
Что думают прохожие -
Знать, клад нашли ребятушки
И делят меж собой...
```